# Probability of Coin Toss 4 times

Tags: probability

Suppose you toss a fair coin four times and observe the sequence of heads and tails.
(a) Select a sample space. What values does the probability function P assign to each of the
possible outcomes?
(b) Suppose you record the number of heads from the four tosses. Find the following probabilities:
(i) P(four heads)
(ii) P(exactly one head)
(iii) P(at least three heads)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: Hello, I am not able to understand what a sample space means here in (a). Is (b)(i) = P(four heads) = P(Exactly one head) = P (atleast one head) = 1/64? as I believe the chances of H/T = 1/2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample space consists of 16 different sequences and all are equally likely with a probability $=\frac{1}{16}$

Sample space $={(HHHH, HHHT, HHTH, HHTT, HTHH, HTHT, HTTH, HTTT, THHH, THHT, THTH, THTT, TTHH, TTHT, TTTH, TTTT)}$

b)

Probability of ( Four heads) $=\frac{1}{16}$

Probability of ( Exactly One head ) $=\frac{4}{16}$

Probability of (Atleast three heads)  $=\frac{5}{16}$